# Save periodically gathered data with python

Tags: python, numpy, csv, serialization, pickle

I periodically receive data (every 15 minutes) and have them in an array (numpy array to be precise) in python, that is roughly 50 columns, the number of rows varies, usually is somewhere around 100-200.

Before, I only analyzed this data and tossed it, but now I'd like to start saving it, so that I can create statistics later.

I have considered saving it in a csv file, but it did not seem right to me to save high amounts of such big 2D arrays to a csv file.

I've looked at serialization options, particularly pickle and numpy's .tobytes(), but in both cases I run into an issue - I have to track the amount of arrays stored. I've seen people write the number as the first thing in the file, but I don't know how I would be able to keep incrementing the number while having the file still opened (the program that gathers the data runs practically non-stop). Constantly opening the file, reading the number, rewriting it, seeking to the end to write new data and closing the file again doesn't seem very efficient.

I feel like I'm missing some vital information and have not been able to find it. I'd love it if someone could show me something I can not see and help me solve the problem.

Comment: Have you considered using a database?

Comment: I have not, but I do not like the thought of that, it seems like too much.

Answer (score 1):

Saving on a csv file might not be a good idea in this case, think about the accessibility and availability of your data. Using a database will be better, you can easily update your data and control the size amount of data you store.